# How to Show/Hide a field based on Picklist value In LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to show a field called **FixedAmount** base on a picklist value and Hide based on another value of the same picklist. Can someone please review the code? It is just displaying for all values but not hiding if I change the value to Fixed Fee

```html
     <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={BusinessType} onchange={handleBusinessTypeChange}></lightning-input-field></div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={AccountName}></lightning-input-field></div>
                    <template if:true={DisplayFixedfee}>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={FixedAmount} disabled={DisplayFixedfee}></lightning-input-field></div>
                    </template>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

```js
    DisplayFixedfee = false;
    
    handleBusinessTypeChange(event){
    console.log(event.detail.value, ' SELECTECTED');
        if(event.detail.value === 'Fixed'){
            this.DisplayFixedfee = true;
            console.log(event.detail.value, ' TRUE');
        } else {
            this.DisplayFixedfee = false;
            console.log(event.detail.value, ' FALSE');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use both `DisplayFixedfee` and `get DisplayFixedfee`; you're trying to create a duplicate property. By the way, you don't need to return true or false when using an inequality operator, because they already return a true or false value. Also, you normally want to use `event.target` in event handlers.

So, you can choose to do *one* of the two following things:

```
get displayFixedFee() {
    return this.businessType === 'Fixed Fee'
}
handleBusinessTypeChange(event) {
    this.businessType = event.target.value
}
```

Or

```
displayFixedFee = false;
handleBusinessTypeChange(event){
    this.displayFixedFee = event.target.value === 'Fixed Fee'
}
```

Finally, since you're new, a bit of advice: only classes and global constants should start with a capital letter (the latter should be ALL_UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES). Variables, properties, component names, event names, and methods should all begin with lower-case letters. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble if you get in the habit of doing this now.